# How to make address search box outside map in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to make an address search box outside the map in leaflet to be as the below picture,i want it to geocode the address written in the address box then appear it on map & its latitude & longitude in another two boxes,i found the plugin `Control.geocoder` in leaflet,but i don't know how to get the results i want, how this can be done?

```
var Mmap = L.map('Modalmap').setView([8.7144, 125.7481],8);
L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"></a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo(Mmap);

var geocoder=L.Control.geocoder().addTo(Mmap);
L.control.locate().addTo(Mmap);
```

[image]

Comment: You can simply create the search form for the geocoding part and then update the map with the result (panning and zooming to the location you got)

Comment: @sabas...can you tell me how to do that?